# Android Json parsing Using Async error executing doInBackground

Tags: android, json, eclipse

I don't know what is the problem here as I am getting error stating " An error occured while executing doInBackground()" Any help will be appreciated. I am a newbie with async please explain if I am wrong.

```
private class childAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
            ChildClass.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> touchpoints = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given string

        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JsonChildString); //testing data from JSON String 

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // Retrieve JSON Objects
                map.put(TEXT, jsonObject.getString("text"));
                map.put(ICON, jsonObject.getString("icon"));

                // set the JOSN Objects into the array
                touchpoints.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_child);

        // getting adapter by passing JSON data arrayList
        adapter = new LazyAdapterNew(ChildClass.this, touchpoints);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Comment: please post your logcat error  -- jsonArray.length() ? were have you got the array its not in the code  please postwhat you are ttrying to parse too

Comment: try after removing "return null;" from your doInBackground() method

Comment: Sorry its my mistake I forgot to declare the jsonArray before the for loop my bad sorry for the disturbance...

Answer (score 0):

i think From doInBackground() the return type is void but your are returning

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>
```

and in post exceute its void but i think it should be

```
 onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> touchpoints)
```

and change the AsyncTask Declaration

Comment: thanks for the help but the problem was I forgot to declare the jsonArray before the for loop
`JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("touchpoints");`

Comment: Instead of doing like that u can return jarray from doInbackground and process that in postexecute.